# How can I chang "1,345.89" to number?

Tags: r

When I use `as.numeric("1,345.89")` to number,it will return "NA",
how can I change it to number correctly?

Comment: `as.numeric(gsub(",","","1,345.89"))`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#Code
number <- "1,345.89"
as.numeric(gsub(',','',number))
```